# What frameworks exist for data subscription and update?

Tags: architecture, client-server, replication

There is one server with multiple clients.  The clients are viewing subsets of the servers entire data.  If the data that a client is viewing changes, the client should be informed of the changes so that it displays the current data.

Example:
Two clients are viewing a list of users in an administration screen.  One client adds a new user to the list and modifies the permissions of another user.  The other client sees the changes propagated to their view.

In the client side code I would like the users list to be updated by the framework itself, raising changed events such that it will be redrawn - similar to '[cells](http://common-lisp.net/project/cells/)' or dataflow.

I am looking specifically for a .NET or java implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very broad so here is my very broad answer: yes, some databases support database-enabled publish-subscribe messaging than can be used to implement "server push".

Comment: @TimothyPratley: [MS SQL Server](http://www.developer.com/net/cplus/article.php/3623546/Using-SQL-Server-to-Implement-the-Publish-Subscribe-Integration-Pattern.htm), [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_pu.htm) and maybe others.